# two datetime picker same value disable

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have two datetime picker as follows

```
 $("#from_date").datetimepicker({

    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'

});

$("#to_date").datetimepicker({

    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',

    maxDate: new Date()

});
```

As you see its "from date" and "two date".

I want a condition that the "from date" and "to date" should not be same also the "to date" should not be less than "from date".

It should not allow me to select "to date" as same as selected "from date" or lower than "from date".

Kindly guide me in achieving this please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589514/datetime-picker-validation-start-date-should-be-less-than-end-date-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime picker validation start date should be less than end date not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589514/datetime-picker-validation-start-date-should-be-less-than-end-date-not-working)

Comment: Did you forget the jQuery tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it likes :

```
 $("#from_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    maxDate: new Date()
 });
 $("#to_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    maxDate: new Date()
 });
```

and :

```
$("#from_date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#to_date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
$("#to_date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var max_date = e.date ? e.date : new Date();
    $('#from_date').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

Comment: In console it says "TypeError: option onShow is not recognized! "

Comment: By the way this is my datetimepicker http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Comment: what is your plugin version !?

Comment: Version 5 from here https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Now i get in console "Empty string passed to getElementById()." in jquery.min.js

Comment: mate can you reply please

Comment: mate sorry , i made issue while copying your code , now the issue changed to "ReferenceError: max_date is not defined"

Comment: in that fiddle it allows me to select two same date mate

Comment: if you don't choice from_date , this date = to_date